# Ajax AutoCompleteExtender (Without WebService) Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to use the Ajax AutoCompleteExtender, but it's not working. Where am I going wrong. Other Ajax controls like update panel, are working fine. Using Chrome.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID = "txtSearch" runat="server">
 <ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
TargetControlID="txtSearch" MinimumPrefixLength="2" EnableCaching="true" 
CompletionSetCount="10" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetCountries">
</ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

public static IEnumerable<string> GetCountries()
 {
   return objDAL.GetCountries(txtSearch.Text.Trim());
 }
```

**DAL:**

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetCountries(string text)
 {
   return MyDB.tblCountries.Where(e=>e.CountryName.StartsWith(text)).
          Select(e=>e.CountryName);
 }
```

Also tried

```
public static List<string> GetCountries()
 {
   return objDAL.GetCountries(txtSearch.Text.Trim()).ToList();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Ajax AutoCompleteExtender without Webservice</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCountry"
MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetCountries" >
</ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetCountries(string prefixText)
    {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Country where CountryName like @Name+'%'", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    List<string> CountryNames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
    CountryNames.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }
    return CountryNames;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have to use linq and layer architecture